# How to configure CLion to pass path variables in CMake options

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm using CLion to work on a CMake project, and I would like to specify paths in the project's "CMake options" with [CLion's path variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/absolute-path-variables.html).  However, when I replace a basedir with CLion's `$PROJECT_DIR`, the path isn't expanded.

Does anyone know if it's possible to use CLion's path variables in CLion's "CMake options" so that the variables are expanded when cmake is being configured?

Answer (score 0):

CLion supports [CMake macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-macros-for-external-tools.html) which can be used in places like its "CMake options" settings.  Their `$CMakeProjectDir$` macro expands to the current project dir, and `$CMakeProjectParentDir$` expands to the project's parent dir.

Comment: In the run config you can see what the variable resolves to from the '+' dialog on the "Working Directory" (etc.) spinner/dropdown.  *Unfortunately*  by default `$CMakeProjectDir$` seems to resolve to nothing.  I have to use `$CMakeCurrentBuildDir$/..` instead...

Comment: @CodeClown42 I confirm `$CMakeProjectDir$` and even `$CMakeParentProjectDir$` work as expected ans without any issue.  You should retrace your steps to check what went wrong.

Comment: And I can confirm, CLion 2023.2.1 on linux, that if you open a new project and the first thing you do is edit a run configuration and set a working directory from the list of pre-defined variables, `$CMakeProjectDir$` is there but in the preview there is no value, just the description "Project root path", and if you select it, no value appears.  I don't recall it ever being different (user for 5 years). I can go in and define it globally via "Appearance and Behavior -> Path Variables", but it has to be a hard-coded path and not something dynamic such as the project root of the current project.

Comment: I do notice that in the full description for CMakeProjectDir it says "local/remote depending on selected toolchain".  I'd presume that means if you are compiling remotely it will be a remote path.  I'm rarely am, but I also notice the default toolchain includes the system cmake and gdb, which I am warned are at least one minor version newer than the ones supported.   They seem to work fine though.  This actually isn't a big deal to me, I just left the comment because I am sure I can not be the only one with this minor problem (eg. the OP here it would seem).  I should file a bug report.